# clone input value to another input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to do is when I update input text ID called `foo` it should be updated real time on input text id called `goo`. I already close to this solution I think but somehow it is not working. please check.

```js
$('#foo').keyup(updatetxt);
$('#foo').keydown(updatetxt);

var foo = $('#foo');

function updatetxt() {
  $('#goo').val(foo);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<input type="text" id="foo" value="something">
<input type="text" id="goo" disabled="disabled" value="something">
```

Comment: In your code `foo` is a jQuery Object and not a string. You will have to fetch `value` of input before setting it to `#goo`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assigning value of one text box to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025338/assigning-value-of-one-text-box-to-another)

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the element to `val()` whereas you need to update the value and that should happen into the function.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>


  <input type="text" id="foo" value="something">
  <input type="text" id="goo" disabled="disabled" value="something">



  <script type='text/javascript'>
    $('#foo').keyup(updatetxt);
    //$('#foo').keydown(updatetxt);

    //var foo = $('#foo').val();

    function updatetxt() {
      $('#goo').val($('#foo').val());
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 same doubt here. Downvoters please state the mistake that i did.

Comment: Because, the answer was missing explanation initially. Second this is a very basic question and user chose to answer instead of marking it as a duplicate. Point is you should look for similar posts when you are answering a basic question. Answering such question will just lead to duplication of content. A user with this rep should know its bad to answer such posts.

Comment: @Rajesh That doesn't mean this answer is wrong. And the reputation is nothing to do here. But I agree your point about explanation.

Comment: @Rajesh The question you linked as duplicate has a fundamentally different issue. This question is asking why the code is not working instead of "how to copy values upon a button click". [It is stated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844) that *If you don't think the question is a duplicate, then by all means do answer it.* The help center also stated that *use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect* instead of on valid answers that are on "believe-to-be duplicate questions".

Comment: @SankarRaj By rep, I meant, you have enough experience to know certain practices. Second, downvote does not mean its wrong answer. It means, it is not required. Hence the vote. Also, SO give close vote privilege only after 3k rep is because by this time you will get to know the good and the bad practices. :-)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Any requirement will always be unique. But the problem statement can be common. Like the issue in OP's code was he was unable to write proper value. So idea answer would be to inform him how to copy. And since the shared link addresses this, it becomes a proper duplicate. Also, I understand that there can be misunderstandings, hence SO required 5 close votes. But answering without even looking for similar posts, in my POV is just wrong.

Comment: @Rajesh I didn't think this is a duplicate. If you have experienced then you can do voting sort of things. I just want to solve this issue and I did it.

Comment: Everyone needs to calm down. If anyone believes that this question needs to be closed as duplicated, feel free to vote for that. But don't downvote answers just because one believe the question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You were very close.  You were just updating with the HTML element, instead of the HTML element value.  Your `updatetxt` function should look like this:

```
var value = $(this).val();
$('#goo').val(value);
```

Comment: A pointer. When you see such a basic question, there us a high possibility that it has been asked before. In such cases, you should look for such post and share its link until you have privilege to close yourself. Answering such question is a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/pyvnkdc2/

```js
$('#foo').keyup(function(){
   $('#goo').val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="foo" value="something">
<input type="text" id="goo" disabled="disabled" value="something">
```

On `keyup` just assign the value to another `input textbox`.

Comment: Why does this solves anything? Is the addressed solution already covered in other answers?

Comment: Please mind the tone. Also, please refer to @Sankar Raj's answer. It already addresses the point of using `.val` to set value. Yes, its not addressing the part of using `this`, but that is not the issue. Issue is OP is not using `.val()` and this has been addressed. So this is a duplication of content. Also *Here you go with a solution* is not an explanation.

Comment: I do not wish to invest any more time in this discussion, but Sankar last edit was for explanation and not code. Also please go through the comment section under his answer, for more opinionated discussion. None the less, in my POV, this answer is not required.